# How to use the Decorator design pattern to nest dependencies in .NET Core DI Container

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have two implementations of interface, and one of them also use this interface:

```
interface IRepository
{
    List<Record> GetRecords(long userId);
}

class Repository : IRepository
{
    public List<Record> GetRecords(long userId)
    {
        return SomeSqlStuff();
    }
}

class RetryingRepository : IRepository
{
    IRepository _repository;

    public RetryingRepository(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    List<Record> GetRecords(long userId)
    {
        try
        {
            return _repository.GetRecords(userId);
        }
        catch
        {
            // some retry logic
        }
    }
}
```

What I need to do in `ConfigureServices()` so that every class gets `RetryingRepository` but `RetryingRepository` gets `Repository` as a dependency?

Comment: This article should be of interest to you https://greatrexpectations.com/2018/10/25/decorators-in-net-core-with-dependency-injection/

Answer (score 4):

There are several hacks you can apply to achieve decoration of dependencies, but it's important to understand that there are limitations to what can be achieved with the default .NET Core DI Container (MS.DI).

#### Option 1: Build the graph by hand:

```cs
services.AddTransient<IRepository>(p =>
    new RetryingRepository(
        new Repository(...)));
```

**Pros:**

- Easy to construct any possible object graph
- Result in easy to follow code for small object graphs

**Cons:**

- Maintenance heavy because every change in the constructor means changing this code (i.e. there is no so-called `Auto-Wiring`).
- Maintenance heavy when you have multiple (or many) `IRepository` implementations that require the decorator.
- The DI Container will not be able to manage the lifetime of your classes.
- Other classes might still need to be resolved from the container, e.g. using `p.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>()`.
- You might lose the possibility for the DI Container to analyze your bindings (not applicable to MS.DI, as it lacks this possibility).

#### Option 2: Let the 'decorator' take a direct dependency on the implementation:

This is the option that Jeremy Lakeman proposes in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66448915/264697).

**Pros:**

- `Auto-Wiring` of both the repository and its decorator are possible.

**Cons:**

- Impossible when the decorator should be wrapped around different implementations.
- Causes sweeping changes through existing decorators' constructors once new decorators need to be added.

#### Option 3: Delegate the creation to ActivatorUtilities

MS.DI contains a helper class called `ActivatorUtilities` that functions as a factory for the DI Container. It allows creating new unregistered types, while resolving its dependencies from the container:

```cs
// This example shows how two decorators are wrapped around Repository
services.AddTransient<Repository>();
services.AddTransient<IRepository>(p =>
    ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<SecurityRepository>(p,
        ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<RetryingRepository>(p,
            p.GetRequiredService<Repository>()));
```

This is effectively the same class that extensions for MS.DI, such as [Scrutor](https://kristian.hellang.com/introducing-scrutor/), use. Scrutor is worth looking at in this regard, because it simplifies the code above, although it is phrone to the same limitations as I'll describe below.

**Pros:**

- `Auto-Wiring` of both the repository and its decorator are possible.
- Allows the decorator to be wrapped around different implementations (doesn't require changing the decorator).
- Allows the decoratee (`Repository`) to have a different lifetime.

**Cons:**

- Hard to manage lifetimes of multiple decorators separately.
- Even though `ActivatorUtilities` is part of MS.DI, it is more fragile. While MS.DI detects cyclic dependencies for you, when using `ActivatorUtilities` you application will fail with a `StackOverflowException` instead.
- Applying decorators to generic classes becomes much harder (use Scrutor or switch to a different DI Container if you need this).
- Applying open-generic decorators to open-generic registrations is impossible.

Answer (score -1):

Typically you only register one implementation of each service for other classes to use.
So register `Repository` as itself (or introduce another interface for this purpose), and `RetryingRepository` as the implementation of `IRepository`.

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IRepository, RetryingRepository>();
services.AddSingleton<Repository>();

...

public RetryingRepository(Repository repository){...}
```